# Enable Run Command in Start Menu for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, run-dialog

My office PC doesnt have RUN option in the Start menu and I tried [this](http://www.merawindows.com/Forums/tabid/324/forumid/15/postid/12896/scope/posts/Default.aspx) to enable but did not work. Any idea?

When I press "Windows + R", I am getting "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator." error message.

Comment: Do you have any error messages or information messages that come up when you press `Windows + R`?

Comment: Yes. "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator."

Comment: Does this account have administrative access? Is this a computer that someone else might have set up for you, for example, at work?

Comment: Yes my company setup this PC for me, however my account has admin rights on this.

Answer (score 2):

You get this message because use of the Run command has been restricted by your system adminstrator through Group Policy which is either controlled on a per-computer basis or, more likely is centrally managed by your admins through Active Directory,

Either way, you can't change this without either local or domain admin rights which its very unlikely that you as a regular user would have

[Updated]

OK, missed the comment. But its still possible that domain policy can override local admin rights if your machine is a member of a domain

Comment: So whatever in my link was the actions I can do for getting RUN window. rite?

Comment: You need to contact the IT dept at your work, ask them if they can enable it for you, they may want it disabled for a reason.